# What url encode algorithm does google or baidu Ads links use

Tags: url, encode, ads

when i search in google

```
http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=shopping&btnG=Search#sclient=psy&hl=en&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=%E8%B4%AD%E7%89%A9&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=d5a61cbe48a951c1
```

then you can see that there are two links in 'Ads' area, but move to your mouse pointer to these links, they are:

```
http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=L&ai=**CYB017kwHTa7GIsT0rQeqnujiCbmK0tEB2dyc_RqQtLWLAQgAEAEoAlCl7byW______8BYJ250IGQBcgBAakCwbO8-f4qhD6qBBlP0FHICrzLP3Yh2d7vTjWYUE8AvmD9DoLL...

http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=L&ai=*CNCTz7kwHTa7GIsT0rQeqnujiCaTU7tsBvOyAshaQtLWLAQgAEAIoAlCe7aiK_P____8BYJ250IGQBcgBAakCwbO8-f4qhD6qBBlP0CHcKLzIP3Yh2cPyGSqYUE8AvmD9DoLL...
```

for China search engine baidu it also encodes the ads links, so can anyone know what encode algorithm they use to encode ads link urls? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that these values act as tokens, linking to the URL in their back-end instead of being an encoded version of the URL itself - as such it would not be possible to convert these values directly to a URL without querying their servers.

Comment: you mean maybe they use like MD5 algorithms+token method to hide the actual url in back-end, since there is token, so it's impossible to decode these ads links? but what's the intention to do this? thank you

Comment: I'd assume it's to do with optimization instead of obscuration. Search engines deal with a great deal of data, and as such quickly accessing that data is imperative to a functional system. This string is more than likely formatted specifically so that the data it relates to can be found quickly and effectively.

There could well be more than an index behind the string, but unless Google plan on documenting this field/request any time soon I doubt we'll ever know what lays behind it.

One other thing to consider, an index is much faster than encryption - another reason I believe it's an index.

Comment: you are right, "It's likely that these values act as tokens", thank you very much for giving me correct direction.